# Can I use a handlebars template in my app.js file

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'm making a portfolio page and I want to have a picture that fades away and displays the text about the image behind it. Which I achieved hardcoding the data.

Like this.

index.html

```
  <div class="col-sm-6">

    <h4>Freelance Work</h4>

    <img src="/images/andersen.png" class="portfolio_pic" id="test_pic">

    <div id="test_text">
      <p>Site for a structural engineer.</p>
      <p><strong>Languages:</strong> JavaScript, HTML, CSS</p>
      <p><strong>Other:</strong> Git, Bootstrap, GoDaddy Hosting</p>
    </div>

    <p><a href="https://andersen-engineering.com/">Andersen Engineering</a></p>
    <p><a href="https://github.com/nwimmer123/david-excel">GitHub Link</a></p>

  </div>
```

styles.css

```
#test_text {
  margin-top: -220px;
  min-height: 210px

}

#test_pic {
  max-height: 250px;
  border: medium groove #660033;
}
```

app.js

```
  $('.test_text').hide();

  $('.test_pic').hover(function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: .1
    }, 200);
    $('.test_text').show();
  }, function () {
    $(this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 500);
    $('.test_text').hide();
  });
```

The problem is when I bring in the same info from my mongoose database, using this code

index.html

```
<div class="col-sm-6"> 
  <div class="list-group" id="portfolio_items-list">
    <script id="portfolio_items-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      {{#each portfolio_items}}
        <h4>{{title}}</h4>

        <img src={{image}} class="portfolio_pic" id="test_pic">

        <div id="test_text">
          <p>{{description}}</p>
          <p><strong>Languages: </strong>{{language}}</p>
          <p><strong>Frameworks: </strong>{{framework}}</p>
          <p><strong>Libraries: </strong>{{library}}</p>
          <p><strong>Database: </strong>{{database}}</p>
          <p><strong>Other: </strong> {{other}}</p>
        </div>

        <p><a href={{sitelink}}>{{sitename}}</a></p>

        <p><a href={{githublink}}>GitHub Link</a></p>

        {{/each}}
    </script>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.js

```
  var source = $('#portfolio_items-template').html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

  //get all database items

  $.get(baseUrl, function (data) {
    var dataHtml = template({ portfolio_items: data});
    $("#portfolio_items-list").append(dataHtml);
  });
```

then there aren't unique ID's for the test_pic and test_text id's so the javascript hide/show/opacity trick doesn't work. I was thinking if I could bring a template into the app.js and load each portfolio_items database id as a unique id for the hide/show/opacity js code, then it might work. the other alternative would be to make unique ids appear in the index/html file via the handlebars template and then copy the hide/show/opacity js code each time with that id hardcoded, but that would be very not DRY.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index of an `{{each}}` loop in handlebars is available by {{@index}} so you can do something like `id="test-pic-{{@index}}` to generate unique ids.

FWIW you can also accomplish the effects you are creating in just .css (see below).

```css
.container {
  width:50%;
  height:250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.container:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}


.text {
  font-size: 2em;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.container:hover .text {
 opacity:1;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">
    <p>hello</p>
    <p>test</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like the css solution, as it's simpler, but it makes all of the portfolio items opaque and show text at the same time. My goal was to only have the item I'm hovering over opaque and show hidden div as you hover over it.

Comment: I also like the {{@index}} thing. I thought that if I put a handlebars inside of a quotes it would just put it in luike a literal, but apparently not! cool.

Comment: for the css, you will want each portfolio item inside it's own `.container` (or whatever class wrapping div) then the hover effect will only apply to that group.